# Large numbers of sleeping queries in MariaDB Process List despite of "wait_timeout" decreased

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I have recently migrated my PHP app to a new server with PHP 7.3 and MariaDB (before it was PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5).
I have some problems with "Too many connections" error.
I suppose that my App has to be improved in order to correct this.
While to do this, I have changed my mariaDB server conf with this values:

```
max_connections         = 600
connect_timeout         = 5
wait_timeout            = 60
interactive_timeout     = 60
```

And despite these enhancements, I still have the same problems, some sleeping process is still existing with a time which exceeds 60 seconds...
And the threads number is increasing... Until the max_coonections value.
And of course, I have restarted the server.

My PHP app is using Mysqli and persistent connection.

Comment: Probably should show the code where you initiate requests and handle responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out, the problem comes from the installation of the server.
I used to change the my.cnf as usual, and some variables are changed at each restart and others no.

And I realised that there is an other conf file, and this file orverwrite the changes I have made in the my.cnf file for some variables...
Now I change the good file, and the server is working as excepting.

So if mariaDB ignore your changes in the conf file check if there is an other file.

Comment: Can you give us the files path involved ?

Comment: There were two files: useless file => /etc/mysql/my.cnf and the good one => /etc/mysql/mariadb.cond.d/50-server.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Simple, stop using persistent connections and restart the server.

Comment: You mean that persistent connections ignore the "wait_timeout" and "interactive_timeout" values ?

Comment: @Wylls how do you think what does "persistent" in the persistent connection mean?

Comment: @Wylls First of all, why do you need persistent connections at all? [This post on DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1559/168229) might be helpful to you, but then there is a question why do you want the connection to be closed after a certain amount of time if you wanted it to be persistent? Persistent usually implies the connection does not get closed at all.

Comment: On my old server I do not need persistant connections. During my test on dev environement I have no problem with connection. So, I move my app on the new server, and few minutes laters, I have error (code 2002)  of connection to the server, no log error on mariadb, and when I start to use persistent connections the problem was fixed. But now I have this new problem...

Answer (score 0):

Although it may see advantageous to increase `max_connections`, it will only make things worse.  It sounds like you have lots of connections stumbling over each other -- none finishing.

Look at `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.  One of the non-Sleeping ones with the largest "Time" (other than 'system' processes) *may* be the main offender.

If the Processlist shows more than, say, 30 connections that are non "Sleep", then lower `max_connections` and the timeouts.  These will help unclog the system, but won't get to the root of the problem.

The "cause" is often one or a few long-running queries that block other connections.  Let's try to find the offending query by using the slowlog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog